# Did my turtle die or did it just ran away?

Tags: turtles

So one day when my turtle was outside in a box with no lids. We went to go do something. Then when we went to check on it, it was gone. There were no clues at the box. Did it get eaten by something or just ran away? Could a snake or any other animal have eaten it? It was a Red-eared slider.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE, with the details you provide, we can only guess what happened to your turtle. Turtles can climb very well, also cats and other animals do like to play with turtle like things very much...

Comment: Do you mean a water turtle or a land tortoise ? I have had both enter my yard ( and pond ) and then leave. It likely walked away , they rarely run, but slow and steady wins the race.

Comment: My son kept a 3 toe box for many years ; he had screen over his outside pen because he read that racoons will eat them.

Comment: You need to at least say what turtle it was

Comment: Red eared slider.

Answer (score 0):

Were you storing it there temporarily or were you expecting that to be its home. If its wild then dont expect it to stay around as turtles like water. If you have a stream, lake, pond or river nearby, check there because it might just be taking a dip or living there and you might have just interrupted its routine.